# Recursion working in Chrome/Firefox but not IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure why this is never completing in IE7, but does in the other browsers. I've put an alert just after the `if (i < l)` and it fires once in IE7 but doesn't continue after that. Any clue?

```
// i, l, object, array, tr, table all determined up here.
function iterate(i, callback) {
    if (i < l) {
        tr = buildTableRow(object[array[i]]);
        tr.attr({
            "id": 'theObjectIs' + array[i]
        });
        table.append(tr);
        i = i + 1;
        iterate(i, callback);
    } else {
        callback();
    }
}

iterate(0, function() {
    alert("Draw Complete");
});
```

Comment: You tested with an alert after `if (i < l) {`, but did you test it anywhere else? Perhaps just before `iterate(i, callback);`? Then if that one doesn't fire, keep moving it back until it does. And I'd suggest `console.log()` instead, especially when doing recursion.

Comment: Use IE8, run it in IE7 mode and set break points in the debugger. Step until it dies.

Comment: @patrick dw: As far as I know console isn't an option w/ IE7.

Comment: Ok, but how about the first half of my comment?

Comment: Could it be a JavaScript error in `buildTableRow` that's causing the code to stop executing after the error occurs in that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, can't see any reason for recursion here. Ordinary loop should work just fine:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    tr = buildTableRow(object[array[i]]);
    tr.attr({
        "id": 'theObjectIs' + array[i];
    });
    table.append(tr);
}
alert("Draw Complete");
```

For the record, you can check the value of `l` in your origianl code (alert?) most probably it's equal to 1 and that's why the function was executed only once.

Edit: the code can break with error in any line inside the loop/recursion thus explaining the problem. Detect such problem using such code:

```
if (i < l) {
    try {
        tr = buildTableRow(object[array[i]]);
        tr.attr({
            "id": 'theObjectIs' + array[i]
        });
        table.append(tr);
    } catch (ex) {
        alert("error occurred at index " + i);
    }
    i = i + 1;
    iterate(i, callback);
} else {
    callback();
}
```

Comment: Recursion and loops are perfectly interchangeably. It's a matter of style and performance.

Comment: @Dykam I was taught to believe recursion should be avoided if possible.. doesn't mean it's "god's command" but personally I think recursion is dangerous so why take a risk when you don't have to?

Comment: O_o run from wherever you learned that... Javascript is a good language for recursion, as it's quite functional.

Comment: @Dykam thanks I'll do some more research when I have time, guess it's up to the OP here to decide which is better in his case. :-)

Comment: @Dykam It's a matter of Stacksize, that's all.

Comment: The reason for recursion and not just a for loop is to give other Javascript on the page a chance to execute. I'm using socket.io w/ node.js and if the loop is making lots of iterations I don't want it to miss a heartbeat from the server and get disconnected.

Comment: @A Wizard Did It - OK fair enough. See my edit for a way to track the problem down and give us better view of what's going on.

Comment: It appears to have been a problem with Date.now() on IE7. In doing `alert(Date.now())` everything works out, but when I apply any sort of math to it it wasn't working... Not sure why, but that fixed it.

Comment: @A Wizard Did It - cheers, Date.now() is not standard JS afaik, you can have `new Date()` to get brand new date object with the current date and time.

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel, platform wise, indeed, but language wise I prefer recursion in a language supporting closures and anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of that recursion is going to be horrible by always updating the DOM with each iteration. If you want to be faster minimize the amount of repaints.

You want to be appending the the tbody and not the table element.

Comment: Sorry, should have probably elaborated or shown more code, the table is actually an element created but not in the DOM yet, I append it to the DOM where the alert is now.